# Many To Many relationship annotation in Jboss 7.1.1 using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, jboss7.x

I've been trying to get the `@ManyToMany` association between my User class and Event class. I have had no such luck. I need an intermediary table to be created to be able to associate an Event with any number of Users following it, and Users can be following any number of Events. This is what I have thus far. I have tried several different examples found, but haven't had much luck.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="school", nullable=false)
    private String school;
    @Column(name="email", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Transient
    private int reputation;

    //@ManyToMany(mappedBy="followers")
    List<Event> followedEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

    @ManyToMany(
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
        mappedBy="followers",
        targetEntity=Event.class
    )
    public List<Event> getEventList(){
      return followedEvents;
    }
    public void setEventList(List<Event> list){
      followedEvents = list;
    }
```

**Event.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title", nullable=false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name="location", nullable=false)
    private String location;
    @Column(name="description", nullable=false)
    private String description;
    @Column(name="date", nullable=false)
    private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    List<User> followers = new ArrayList<User>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=User.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "EVENT_USER",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}
    )
    public List<User> getFollowers(){
        return followers;
    }
    public void setFollowers(List<User> followers){
        this.followers = followers;
    }
```

The code runs, but it is not creating an intermediary table that holds the association between the two. Instead the serialized ArrayList is held. Any help understanding why it hasn't been doing whats expected would be much appreciated.

If it matters I'll include where I am actually persisting the Event:

```
public boolean attemptAttending(int eventId, String userName){
        User u = null;
        Event e = null;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, User.class);
            q.setParameter(1, userName);
            for(User user : (ArrayList<User>)q.getResultList())
                u = user;

            query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = ?";
            q = em.createNativeQuery(query, Event.class);
            q.setParameter(1, eventId);
            for(Event event : (ArrayList<Event>)q.getResultList())
                e = event;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        e.getFollowers().add(u);
        em.persist(e);

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an ArrayList to hold an association. You must use a collection interface instead: `Collection`, `List` or `Set`. Hibernate replaces your ArrayList with its own PersistentList, which handles dirty chcking, lazy loading, etc. And anyway, it's always a good idea to program on interfaces rather than implementations.

```
private List<Event> followedEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

@ManyToMany(...)
public List<Event> getEventList(){
    return followedEvents;
}
public void setEventList(List<Event> list){
    followedEvents = list;
}
```

Comment: Thats makes sense. Thanks for clarifying that! Though I have gotten a different error. Am I doing anything else wrong? I am defining the types correctly... I think `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(followedEvents)]`

Comment: Show us the complete entity. It seems your Id annotation is on the field, but your ManyToMany annotation is on the getter. You must be consistent.

Comment: I actually have no idea what you mean. Like I mention most of the tutorials I have gone through are limited on overall information. I added the other important fields unless you want me to add everything  in the entities.

Comment: All your annotations (@Id, @Column, etc.) are placed on the fields of your entity. The instance variables if you prefer. The attributes if you prefer. Except the ManyToMany annotation, which is placed on the getter method (`getEventList()`). It should be placed, as all the other annotations, on the field (`private List<Event> followedEvents`). Same thing for the Event entity, of course.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of the examples showed both ways being used. I do have a question. So if I decided to have my annotation on the getters instead, they just have to be consistently there?

Comment: Yes. IIRC, Hibernate only considers annotations that are placed at the same location as the Id location. So if Id is on a field, everything should be on a field. If Id is on the getter, everything should be on getters.